# Using Backbone.history to go back without triggering route function

Tags: backbone.js

I have a modal popup which when opened changes the URL. When a user closes the popup I want to go back to the previous URL but I don't want to trigger the route associated with that URL because that will reload my collection and render the view etc. Is there a way to call`window.history.back()`without triggering the route, or is there a backbone equivalent of this?

The only solution I can think of would be to save the previous route, then when the modal is closed call

```
Backbone.history.navigate(route, {trigger: false, replace: true});
```

but this seems like a complex way to solve an easy problem.

Comment: My suggestion (and I'm sorry that it doesn't answer your question at all) is to consider what would happen if they bookmark your page while the popup is displayed.  If they return directly to http://yoursite.com/#popup/route it may behave oddly.  If it doesn't behave oddly, then what would happen if they close the modal dialog?  In my experience, I haven't used the routers to cause a modal dialog for these reasons.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: If they bookmark the page, and then return to yoursite.com/#popup/route it will redirect them to a static html version of that popup at yoursite.com/popup/route, so there is no option to close the popup.

Answer (score 5):

Storing history in a router sounds like a good solution to me, I couldn't figure out better way to solve this problem.

A good solution of that is here: 
[Silently change url to previous using Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416074/silently-change-url-to-previous-using-backbone-js)

I would do a minor tweak so it would look like this:

```
class MyRouter extends Backbone.Router

  initialize: (options) ->
    @on "all", @storeRoute
    @history = []

  storeRoute: ->
    @history.push Backbone.history.fragment

  previous: ->
    if @history.length > 1
      @navigate @history[@history.length-2], false
    else
      @navigate '', true
```

Then you can just call MyRouter.previous(), and if you came by direct request, it will bring you to your root.

I wish it were a default feature of the router, at least so that it keeps 5 last routes.